# Watch Later text not changing, in django

Tags: django-views, django-templates

i was creating a django project for anime display, and used kitsu.py to fetch anime details. In my models i had watchlater:

```
    class WatchList(models.Model):
        anime_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} - {self.anime_id}',
```

and in my urls.py i have

```
    path('anime/<int:anime_id>/', views.get_anime, name='get_anime'),
    path('in_watchlater', views.in_watchlater, name="in_watchlater"),
```

and in my anime_details.html, the code for watchlater is :

```
    <form action="{% url 'in_watchlater'%}" method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <input type="hidden" name="anime_id" value="{{anime.id}}">
           {% comment %} <input type="hidden" name="unwatch" value="{{ unwatch }}"> {% endcomment %}
           <button type="submit">
               {%if not unwatch%}Add to WatchLater
               {%else %}Remove from WatchLater
                {%endif%}
          </button>
         </form>
```

in my views.py, i have :

```
async def get_anime(request, anime_id):
    client = kitsu.Client()
    anime = await client.get_anime(anime_id)
    # Fetch genres and await the coroutine
    genres = [genre.title for genre in await anime.categories]
    streaming_links = [{'title':streams.title,'url':streams.url} for streams in await anime.streaming_links]
    def get_unwatch_status(anime_id):
        unwatch = request.session.get('unwatch', {})
        if isinstance(unwatch, bool):  # If unwatch is a boolean
            unwatch = {}  # Initialize it as an empty dictionary
        request.session['unwatch'] = unwatch
        request.session.save()
        return unwatch.get(anime_id, False)
    # Call the synchronous function using sync_to_async
    unwatch = await sync_to_async(get_unwatch_status)(anime_id)
    return render(request, 'anime/anime_details.html', context={
                                                        'anime': anime, 'genres': genres, 
                                                        'streaming_links':streaming_links,
                                                        'unwatch': unwatch,
                                                        })
```

and

```
def in_watchlater(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        anime_id = request.POST.get('anime_id')  # Use get() to avoid KeyError
        user = request.user
        unwatch = request.session.get('unwatch', {})  # Get the unwatch dictionary from the session

        if isinstance(unwatch, bool):  # If unwatch is a boolean
            unwatch = {}  # Initialize it as an empty dictionary

        if anime_id in unwatch and unwatch[anime_id]:  # If this anime is already marked as unwatch
            WatchList.objects.filter(user=user, anime_id=anime_id).delete()  # Remove it from watchlist
            unwatch[anime_id] = False  # Set its unwatch status to False
        else: 
            watchlist_item, created = WatchList.objects.get_or_create(user=user, anime_id=anime_id)  # Add it to watchlist or get it if it already exists
            if created:
                unwatch[anime_id] = True  # Set its unwatch status to True only if it was created
        # Store unwatch in session
        request.session['unwatch'] = unwatch
        request.session.modified = True

        return redirect('get_anime', anime_id=anime_id),
```

i think the issue is with get_anime() method as unwatch in there always comes out to be false, maybe that is the reason, but i cant figure out how to work for it...